# What is the difference between Dock and Anchor

Tags: c#, .net, dock, docking

I have a windows form which have a lot of controls in
that(Listbox,Groupbox,Combobox,TextBox,ListBox etc). I need to resize
and arrange the controls automatically whenever the form's size gets
changed. I need to know the difference between Dock and Anchor to
implement this. **What is the actual difference between Docking and
Anchoring?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docking and Anchoring on a Windows Form application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673236/docking-and-anchoring-on-a-windows-form-application)

Comment: "a lot of controls" doesn't help you use Anchor/Dock to implement automatic layout.  You *might* get somewhere with TableLayoutPanel, having to use the Resize event and move stuff around yourself is not uncommon if the layout is not well grouped.  It depends.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Anchor and Dock properties of a form are two separate properties.

**Anchor** refers to the position a control has relative to the edges of the form. A textbox, for example, that is anchored to the left edge of a form will stay in the same position as the form is resized.

**Docking** refers to how much space you want the control to take up on the form. If you dock a control to the left of the form, it will stretch itself to the height of the form, but its width will stay the same.

This [EXAMPLE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2231/Working-with-Anchoring-and-Docking-Properties) can help you understand a bit more.

Comment: So whats the difference between DockStyle.Left and .Right as you're saying both will stretch theirself to the height of the form?

Comment: @duesterdust Yes, both stretch to the height of the form, but the width you set manually doesn't change, and DockStyle.Left glues the control to the left side of the form and .Right does it to the other side.