# Defining the size and position of the client area of a form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have to define the size and position of the form's client area.

I have viewed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277039/how-to-set-the-client-area-clientrectangle-in-a-borderless-form) and used the below code for defining the client area of the form.

```
 private void On_Wm_NcCalcSize(ref Message m)
    {
        NativePaint.RECT rect = new NativePaint.RECT();
        NativePaint.GetWindowRect((int)this.Handle, ref rect);

        rect.top += CaptionHeight;
        rect.left += borderWidth;
        rect.right -= borderWidth;
        rect.bottom -= borderWidth;

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.LParam, true);
    }
```

It works perfectly. But I can't able to understand the purpose of the method call **Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.Lparam, true)**.

I have analyzed about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261468(v=vs.110).aspx).
But I can't understand the reason for using the method in this scenario.

Is this the only way to customize the client area?

Can anyone please share your knowledge.

Comment: Sounds like an x-y problem. Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: that's what I don't know. Is there any possibilities to define the client area without using this.?

Comment: I meant: Why do you want to 'change the clientarea?'. - Also: Does that mean you want it to be different from just the full window area minus borders and minus title??

Comment: I have to increase the size of the title bar. For that I am need of this.

Comment: This is very hard! Instead I suggest to remove the titltebar altogether and simulate one of you own. -  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751715/adding-buttons-to-side-of-window-on-windows-form/42812851#42812851) for an example to workaround the issue! (It seems to be about transparency, but the top label acts as a title bar!!)