# How can i do to the buttons follow the maximize size of the screen in Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, maximize

I developed a form in the size : 810;450 but i want to use it maximized. The problem is: i need that the components,that are inside the form, to fit in the screen maximized aswell.

Comment: > You can use Dock and anchor property of your controls to achieve what
> you want **Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581535/what-is-the-difference-between-dock-and-anchor)**

Comment: C# tag and VBA?  Which is it?